# Error with bash script "exit code 126"

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, xcode, bash

I want integrate CPD (Copy-Paste-Detection) to my iOS project. I read about it [here](http://deadmeta4.com/2011/05/17/objective-c-copy-paste-detection-using-jenkins/) and [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137875/).

To automatically determine CopyPaste in the code I'm using bash script:

```
echo "Checking files in ${SOURCE_ROOT}"
JARS_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/CPD
FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT=${PROJECT_DIR}/cpd-output.xml

# Running CPD
java -classpath "${JARS_DIR}/ObjCLanguage-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar:${JARS_DIR}/pmd.jar" net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.CPD --minimum-tokens 100 --files "${SOURCE_ROOT}" -v --language ObjectiveC --encoding UTF-8 --format net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.XMLRenderer > "${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"

# Running self :)
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} -cpd-xml "${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"
```

That code create cpd-output.xml file. But take me an error at compile time "Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 126". Here is log copy http://pastebin.com/359k1Wni
I took the code from this [example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45054714/CPDObjective-C.zip)
Error is going then I comment this string:

```
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} -cpd-xml "${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"
```

I tried to find what ever information about this error, but found only a few of these problems without answers. I'm not know anything about bash scripting. I will be happy with any advice. 
Thank you for your attention.

P.S. Author of following the script written:

> In order to integrate XCode and the CPD, we will add to the Build
>   Phases target with the project, Run Script phase, conventionally
>   consisting of several parts: Actually calling cpd Parsing
>   cpd-output.xml Output in the "right format"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the wrong script. I give a revised script, which logs have been added:

```
echo "Checking files in ${SOURCE_ROOT}"
CPD_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/CPD
JARS_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/CPD
FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT=${PROJECT_DIR}/cpd-output.xml
OBJC_JAR_LIBRARY=${JARS_DIR}/ObjCLanguage-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar

echo [DEBUG] CPD_DIR = ${CPD_DIR}
echo [DEBUG] JARS_DIR = ${JARS_DIR}
echo [DEBUG] FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT = ${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}
echo [DEBUG] OBJC_JAR_LIBRARY = ${OBJC_JAR_LIBRARY}
echo [DEBUG] SOURCE_ROOT = ${SOURCE_ROOT}

# Running CPD
java -classpath "${OBJC_JAR_LIBRARY}:${JARS_DIR}/pmd.jar" net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.CPD --minimum-tokens 200 --files "${SOURCE_ROOT}" -v --language ObjectiveC --encoding UTF-8 --format net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.XMLRenderer > "${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"

CPD_EXECUTABLE="${CPD_DIR}/CPDObjective-C"
if [ ! -f "${CPD_EXECUTABLE}" ];
then
echo "CPD executable file is not found: " ${CPD_EXECUTABLE}
fi
echo "Running ${CPD_EXECUTABLE} -cpd-xml ${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"
"${CPD_EXECUTABLE}" -cpd-xml "${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"
```

Here is source code of [sample Copy-Paste-Detect](http://goo.gl/BIQ3g)

Comment: If you have any files named `D` or `E` or `B` or `U` or `G`, the unquoted `[DEBUG]` will be interpreted as a wildcard and expanded into a list of those files (also depending on some shell options), The obvious fix is to quote your strings. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642

Answer (score 21):

The error may also be caused due to inadequate "Permissions" to run the Shell.
I got:-

    `bash: /home/XXX.sh: Permission denied
    exit-status: 126` 


On fixing the permissions on shell script, the issue got fixed.

Comment: I ran into this issue while trying to build for Docker. Thanks for your fix.

Comment: `chmod +x foo.sh` to allow execution

Answer (score 17):

> 126 for “command not executable"

```
# Running self :)
${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} -cpd-xml "${FULL_PATH_TO_CPD_XML_OUTPUT}"
```

It looks like $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR} is not executable
Can you update with the value of this var please

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not know anything about bash scripting. I added the words of the author of this script.

Comment: Essentially your application does not have permission from the bash shell to run $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}. How to do that will depend on the code you copied from the project.  I will try to take a look at it, but I don't know Objective C (assuming thats what its in).  I will update if i figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Like the error message in the pastebin says, the value of `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}` is a directory (line 314).  It doesn't make any sense to attempt to execute a directory, so it appears that the build script is broken or corrupted.

By the by, are the `setenv` commands part of the script as well?  This is typically a `csh` command, not a `sh` or `bash` command.  Executing a directory doesn't make sense under `tcsh` either, though, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

This is now *years* later, but the answer is found in the [bash man page](https://manpages.org/bash) in the EXIT STATUS section:

> If a command is not found, the child process created to execute it returns a status of 127. If a command is found but is not executable, **the return status is 126.**